# How I get the container info on dockerless systems?

Tags: docker, redhat, podman

I am trying to get rid of docker on Linux system. I may need to make it on RedHat/CentOS. I need to get the container info like names, id, image etc. Podman kind of resolves this problem. But I am wondering if there is another way to make it besides of using podman.

Comment: You mean something like "buildah" or are you talking about just exploring the files under the docker root dir? (/var/lib/docker in centos/rhel).

Comment: By exploring the docker root dir. I know I can get the name of container, it's the folder name. But the other info seems to not be available.